# Pointer size not correct

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What the pointer size in 64 bits computer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841405/what-the-pointer-size-in-64-bits-computer-in-c)

I'm studing C at The University.

I try to setup an environment for programming on Windows 7/8 and have a problem

This code:

```
int main()
  int *p;
  printf("%d",sizeof(p));
  return 0;
}
```

prints 4 instead of 8 (8 is printed in University).
What can i do?

My Windows is 64bit and x64 processor.

Comment: Probably your compiler compiles the code for x86 CPUs. What's the compiler and what options are incliuded? Visual Studio? If so, you should make it compile x64 bit applications, as far as I remember, by default, it compiles 32bit apps.

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but `sizeof` returns a `size_t`. When you call `printf("%d", ...` you print it as an `int`. You should use `printf("%zu", ...` or simply cast the result of `sizeof` to `int`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq shouldn't that be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @PascalCuoq
Pascal, did you mean %lu? because %lu is what was in the example, i by mistake set %d.
When i compile with %lu it says that "expects argument of long unsigned int, but argument 2 has type int * "
Btw with lu warning after compile it prints 8.

Comment: @AndreyDobrikov he said `%zu` not `%lu`. My K&R booksays `%u` for unsigned int as decimal, so might be worth trying that. Hopefully Pascal will expand on it in an answer.

Comment: Try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express) Should be what you're looking for.

Comment: when i try %zu it says unknows conversion type character "z"...

Comment: BTW my compiler is minGW's gcc.

Comment: So how do i check the length of a pointer on my system?

Comment: Never mind, its still 4 bytes... :(

Comment: @GajananH in duplicate i dont have answer to my question, im used to eclipse and dont want to change to vs.

Comment: `%zu` is the format one should use for printing values of type `size_t`. More description can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943869/139746 . I am not putting this as an answer because it won't solve the unrelated 4/8 issue that the question really is about. If the compiler does not support `%zu`, then workarounds are `printf("%d",(int)sizeof(...` or `printf("%lu",(unsigned long)sizeof(...`

Comment: @AndreyDobrikov Could you post the compilation command which eclipse is using ?

Comment: `%zu` was introduced with C99; if you're using a C89 or earlier compiler, you'll need to use `%lu` and cast the result of `sizeof` to `unsigned long`: `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) sizeof p);`

Comment: Thanks ALL, you help me a lot doing my first steps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably compile the code into 32 bit application. You need to compile it as 64 bit application. Check your compiler settings. It does not matter that your OS is 64 bit.

Comment: Ok so which compiles can i use to compile as 64 bit app?
My compiler is minGW gcc.

Comment: @AndreyDobrikov: I would use VS 2012, but it is more a C++ compiler. For C you can try mingw-w64.

Comment: @AndreyDobrikov try `-m64` as compiler argument.

Comment: @RedX -m64 "sorry, unimplemented: 64 bit mode not compile in.

Comment: @JurajBlaho is there mingw-w64 exe? or how i use it? when i try to download i get *.tar file with no bin and no gcc.exe...

Comment: You can find the binary automated builds here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/ and i think the right one should be http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/mingw-w64-bin_i686-cygwin-1.7.7-1_20121015.tar.bz2/download

Comment: @RedX Thank you i will try to install this!

Comment: Does anyone know how to deal with eclipse's "launch failed. Binary not found"? (eclipse juno)

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" here is results depending on the compile architecture.

Basic types in C (like e.g. `int`, `double`, `char`) do not have a predefined size; it is up to the compiler which size to use for which type.

As for pointers, you typically want to be able to address any memory location available on your machine.
On 32 bit architectures, the address range is 2^32. As a pointer is nothing more than a number referring to the address the memory is located at, 2^32 addresses (i.e., a range of 4 Bytes) suits just fine.

For 64 bit systems, in order to address all memory, a range of 2^64 (i.e. 8 bytes) is necessary.

Therefor, pointer sizes need to depend on the system architecture.

Keep in mind: all pointer types (be it `int*, char*, double*` or whatever) have the same size! Using integers and integer pointers on 32 bit can therefor be a bit confusing, as an `int` has a size of 4 bytes on most architectures, as well.