# Size of pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, 32bit-64bit

1. What's the size of a pointer in C in a 32-bit machine using a 32-bit Compiler?
2. What's the size of a pointer in C in a 64-bit machine using a 32-bit compiler?

Comment: `printf ("%d\n", sizeof (void*)) ;`

Comment: This might help: [What the pointer size in 64 bits computer in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841405/what-the-pointer-size-in-64-bits-computer-in-c)

Comment: @Ben Zotto There are many amateurs to downvote questions.:) Usually they have nothing to answer a question.:)

Comment: Honestly, the OP does not demonstrate any effort to solve the questions on his own. Usually it is expected to introduce the problem in a clear and concise manner (check), and highlight the difficulties that have prevented from solving the problem himself (not check).

Comment: @Daniel Kleinstein  At least I do not see any substantial answer.

Comment: It's not possible to give direct answer your question as it is. Please name the platform and compiler, as it will be relevant to the answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If you are unhappy with the answers, then please provide one yourself.

Comment: @trojanfoe  I am unhappy with downvotes of the question. Reread my first comment. You should redirect your comment to whose who downvoted the question. They have nothing to say except off-topic comments.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was referring to your comment "At least I do not see any substantial answer".

Comment: @trojanfoe  I have not downvoted the question opposite to others.

Answer (score 6):

The machine is not relevant, provided a 64-bit Operating system is capable of runnning 32-bit apps (most are); it depends on the type of executable you create (`-m32` etc.).

You can answer this yourself by compiling and running the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    printf("Pointer size is %u bytes\n", (unsigned)sizeof(void *));
    return 0;
}
```

The answer will be 4 (32-bits).

Comment: Does this size depends on what? Compiler or Machine Architecture?

Comment: @NAVEEN It depends on whether you tell the compiler to create a 32- or 64-bit executable.  The GNU compiler, for example, uses `-m32` or `-m64` to define the type.  `clang` under OSX uses `-arch x86` or `-arch x86_64` and the Microsoft compiler uses `/MACHINE:X86` and `/MACHINE:X64`.

Comment: @trojanfoe This does not answer the question. It only advices how to check the size of pointer in some particular implementation.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Please note the "The answer will be 4 (32-bits)." at the end.

Comment: @trojanfoe That is a guess really. Correct answer would have been *"It's implementation defined"*.

Comment: @user694733 He can check for himself and I have shown him how.  Can you tell me of any 32-bit systems that would not return `4` as the answer?

Comment: @user694733: No, trojanfoe answered correctly. Re-read the question carefully. He's asking two very specific questions. Both questions boil down to the last bit, which states "using 32-bit compiler" and hence, the answer will be 32 bits.

Comment: Pointer size does't depends on any under lying architecture. It would be given as option during compilation. But recommended to use -M64  for 64 bit machine so it can access beyond 4GB.

Comment: @NAVEEN Even on a 32-bit operating system?  How so?

Comment: If it 32 bit OS on 64 bit machine, all  binaries should be compiled with -m32 bit option. So pointer size is 32 bit.

Comment: @trojanfoe Is there a particular reason why you cast the result of sizeof to unsigned instead of doing `printf("Pointer size is %zu bytes\n", sizeof(void *));`?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Because I didn't know about the `%zu` format specifier :)